# Follow iOS 7's Default UINavigationController transition?

Tags: ios, animation, ios7

I want to keep the default UINavigationController push and pop transition (including the interactivity), but I want to perform some other animations along with the animation. Is there a way to subscribe to progress notifications so I can find out how far along the interactive transition is and perform my own animations?

I know I could basically re-create the default animation using my own animator and interaction controller, but that's quite a bit of work and I'm worried that my duplication won't exactly match the default behavior.